# Access phpMyAdmin from every network in Android

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

I have written an Android code and connected with webserver (phpMyAdmin). Now the problem comes I can only access the server from only one network i.e my own internet,whenever I try to access it from other network it gives me volley.timeout error.

Some suggests me to make your server address public and some suggests me to buy a server. I don't about these things quite well as I am new to Android and I want access my database from every network.

Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button Show;
TextView Result;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String URL="http://192.168.0.103/fetchdata.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Show=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Show);
    Result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    Show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectrequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    try{
                        JSONArray signin=response.getJSONArray("signin");
                        for (int i=0;i<signin.length();i++)
                        {

                            JSONObject signin1=signin.getJSONObject(i);

                            String Username=signin1.getString("username");
                            String Password=signin1.getString("password");
                            String Email=signin1.getString("email");


                            Result.append(Username+" "+Email+" "+Password+ "\n");
                        }

                        Result.append("===\n");
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            requestQueue.add(jsonobjectrequest);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you first have to configure your phpMyAdmin.

You have to edit this file

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

In the linux console enter the following command

```
$ sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf.
```

add the additional line to the directory settings:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/> <----- or similar 
    order deny,allow 
    deny from all 
    allow from 127.0.0.1 
    allow from 192.168.1.0/15 <--- Add this 
</Directory>
```

If you wanted to allow access to everybody then you could just change it to:

```
 <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/> 
     order allow,deny 
     allow from all 
 </Directory>
```

Save, and just restart the server

```
 $ sudo service httpd restart
```